# How to change the colors of weekends in v-calendar (different colors for saturdays and sundays respectively)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, calendar, vcalendar

As the title suggests,
I'd like to change the colors of the weekends in my calendar (and different colors for both weekends..)

this is my component for the v-calendar

```
<div id='app'>
<v-date-picker
  title-position="left" 
  :columns="layout.columns"
  :rows="layout.rows"
  :is-expanded="layout.isExpanded"
  :attributes="attributes" 
  :masks="{ title: 'YYYY年 MMM' }"
  :model-config="modelConfig"
  :disabled-dates="disabledDates"
  :first-day-of-week = 2
  @dayclick = "clickCalendar"
  v-model = "selectedDate"
></v-date-picker>
<p v-if="calendarIsClicked">押された日は "{{ selectedDate }}"</p>
```

and this is the vue js code

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      calendarIsClicked: false,
      selectedDate: null,
      attributes: [{
        key: "today",
        highlight: {
          style: {
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            opacity: 0.5
          }
        },
      }],
      disabledDates: {
        weekdays: this.fetchClosedDates()
      },
      modelConfig: {
        type: "string",
        mask: "YYYY-MM-DD"
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    clickCalendar(day) {
      this.calendarIsClicked = true
    },

    fetchClosedDates() {
      return [1, 7]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    layout() {
      return this.$screens({
        // Mobile Layout
        default: {
          columns: 1,
          rows: 1,
          isExpanded: true,
        },
        // PC Layout
        lg: {
          columns: 2,
          rows: 2,
          isExpanded: false,
        },
      });
    }
  }
})
```

at the moment, it was possible to disable the dates but I'd like to disable AND add colors to them..
and maybe add some disabled cursor when hovered over them..

Comment: what is `v-date-picker`? where does it come from?

Comment: v-date-picker is usable component out of the box from v-calendar.js

Comment: Oh, ok - the `vcalendar` tag put me off since it's nothing at all to do with `v-calendar.js`

Comment: Have you seen the documentation https://vcalendar.io/ ... the last example has weekends that are a different colour, and there's a link to a github that shows you exactly how it's done using CSS

Comment: omg, i genuinely thought vcalendar is v-calendar.. sorry for the confusion and yeah I checked it out but I don't really know how to apply it to my code since mine is just written in normal index.html and the example is used with vue cli slot components..

Comment: the answer is css

Comment: it was actually just css.. thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Can you inspect HTML element? Just change CSS for column Saturday and Sunday

Comment: I change the css for weekends columns and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @ThihaHtunNaing if you add your solution as answer it can be marked as accepted. It would help other people to understand the changes that you made in detail. More precisely: What did you use as CSS selector for the columns? From what I can tell, the generated HTML does not seem to have a CSS class (or something similar) for week-days.